# Can i store string in <Application.Resources> and bind to it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm using Microsoft's AdControl on several pages... but in order to simplify it i would like to store ApplicationId once and read it as a resource.

Could it be possible to use  in the App.xaml and then in the control set the binding to it? But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"{StaticResource name}"` just like you would with `<Page.Resources>`

To store the resource, create a new `<ResourceDictionary>` in `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` and place your resource in that.

For example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- 
                Styles that define common aspects of the platform look and feel
                Required by Visual Studio project and item templates
             -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <x:String x:Key="Foo">Bar</x:String>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```